# Is there a natural way to totally order the set of unlabeled binary trees on $n$ nodes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory

Let $C_n$ be the $n^{th}$ Catalan number. There are $C_n$ unlabeled binary trees having $n$ internal nodes.  I want to totally order these trees in some (hopefully not too complicated) natural manner.  Perhaps there is some "standard" way of doing this.  When I look at pictures of, say the 14 binary trees on 4 nodes, they never seem to be listed in any particular order.  Notice that what I want to order is the trees themselves not the vertices within each tree.

I tried classifying by height and then by height of shortest branches from left to right but I'm not sure if what I have is correct.  I think there must be some well known way to order these trees?

Comment: Biject them to Dyck paths and lexicographically order them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ and $T$ be binary trees. Provided $S$ and $T$ are nontrivial, we write $S=(S^L,S^R)$ and $T=(T^L,T^R)$. An ordering on trees is determined recursively as follows:
$$
S\le T\iff \begin{cases}
S=\text{trivial tree}&\text{or}\\
S^L<T^L & \text{or}\\
S^L=T^L\text{ and }S^R\le T^R
\end{cases}
$$
Roughly, trees are ordered in terms of simplicity, with preference given to the left subtree, so this is a recursive lexicographic order. For example, when $n=3$,

[image]

Comment: How does this differ from my suggestion?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I see now my answer gives the same ordering as yours.

Comment: (+1) because (in my opinion) it's no bad thing to have two or more answers that express the same idea in different ways. It's also reassuring that we had the same idea, because that makes it seem all the more "natural".

Answer (score 2):

For $k = 0$ to $n - 1$ (or vice versa) enumerate all the possible left subtrees with $k$ nodes. For each possible left subtree with $k$ nodes, enumerate all the possible right subtrees with $n - k - 1$ nodes. Recursively, this gives for every positive integer $n$ a fairly natural way to totally order the set of all unlabeled binary trees with $n$ nodes, by referring to the same procedure to totally order the set of all trees with any given smaller number of nodes.